# Authlogic Base.named_scope Deprecation Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

I'm using **Authlogic 2.1.6** in **Rails 3.0.1.**
Everything works fine but I am consistently getting the same two errors, which stem from the acts_as_authentic command in my user model.

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Base.named_scope has been deprecated, please use Base.scope instead. (called from <class:User> at /Developer/Products/sphr/app/models/user.rb:271)
```

I recall seeing an Authlogic commit that claimed to have fixed this bug but I can't find it.
Could you please tell me how to stop seeing these messages?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please post line 271 of your User model?

Comment: @Beerlington It's going to be a call to `acts_as_authentic`, like he said.

Comment: @coreyward - sorry, just seemed strange to me that it would be called that far down in a model

Comment: @Beerlington Agreed. Maybe after lots of validations? #wishfulthinking

Comment: @Beerlington Line 271 is indeed acts_as_authentic.  I dropped it at the very end of the file after a ton of business logic, validation, and associations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calls to the deprecated methods have not been fixed in the master [Authlogic repository](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic). There are about [two dozen pull requests](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/pulls) fixing them on Github, though. If you feel so inclined, you can simply change your Gemfile to point to one of them instead.

```
gem 'authlogic', :git => 'git://github.com/exceed/authlogic.git'
```

**Update**: Those pull requests have finally been integrated in and you can use the standard gem again.